# I have the javascript code getElementsByClassName how it will be on php?

Tags: javascript, php, xml

i have this code on javascript

```
String(document.getElementsByClassName('ord-total-val')[0].innerText).substr(0,3)
```

this cod grab class element 'ord-total-val', and returns its text string to me.
I try this:

```
$classname="blockProduct";
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$spaner = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

But my knowledge is not enough to complete it.
Can you help my to write this stroke on php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be fair your code is virtually complete and appears to work OK when I combined it with a basic test case.

```
<?php


    $strhtml="<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style></style>
        <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>wibble wobble</p>
        <div class='blockProduct'>whoohoo! Some text</div>
        <p>lorem ipsum dolor solit...</p>
        <span class='blockProduct'>and even more text in a different HTML element</span>
    </body>
</html>";


    $className='blockProduct';


    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($strhtml);
    
    $xp=new DOMXPath($dom);
    $expr='//*[ contains( @class, "'.$className.'" ) ]';
    
    $col=$xp->query( $expr );
    if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $node ){
            $text=$node->nodeValue;
            $substr=substr($text,0,3);
            
            echo $substr . '<br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

Given the HTML source above this will output:

```
who
and
```

Using your code, but modified just slightly to use the XPath object already created, `$xp`:

```
$spaner = $xp->query("//*[contains(@class, '$className')]");
```

This gives a `nodelist` so you need to iterate through this `nodelist` to show the contents.

```
foreach($spaner as $span)echo $span->nodeValue;
```